# How to get current GoogleMap zoom level?

Tags: android, google-maps

On GoogleMap android API v2, how do I get the current map zoom level? On API v1, there used to be `float MapView.getZoomLevel()`, but there appears to be nothing similar on the API version I am using, and that Google recommends.

I've thought of using a class variable to save the zoom level manually via a zoom button click listener, but this doesn't solve the problem for pinch-type zooming.

Why do I need the current zoom level? I am restricting the map range to a certain rectangle and want any moves that would otherwise leave this rectangle, bounce back. This animation requires me to use a zoom level, for without it, the default maximum zoom level is used. What I really want is to maintain the zoom level used before the move attempt.

```java
protected void recenterMap() {
    map.getMinZoomLevel();
    if(MAP_BOUNDS.contains(map.getCameraPosition().target) == false) {
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(MAP_CENTER)      
        .zoom(current_zoom)
        .build();     

        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    } else {
        MAP_CENTER = map.getCameraPosition().target;
    }
}
```

Notice that the variable `current_zoom` is what I need to define.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

For Android, try getting the current CameraPosition, and getting the zoom from that.
I believe it's:

```
map.getCameraPosition().zoom
```

Comment: (it's been a while since I touched it on Android itself..)

Comment: Wow, did not expect getting the zoom directly from the class (without methods)!

Answer (score -4):

It should be (on v2 API)

```
map.getZoom();
```

If not, try `document.getElementById("zoom").innerHTML`

Comment: Same comment as above, this answer would be fine for javascript, But I am using Google Maps API v2 for android.

Comment: Yea, I didn't realize this was for android either.

Comment: Whoops :) Sorry... I missed the ANDROID part myself